# How can I go to path and execute a 'node 'command in bash as one-liner?

Tags: bash

Usually I do this:

```
cd $HOME
cd Desktop
cd project_folder

node server.js
```

Now it's time to increase efficicency and do one-liner.

I want to do this:

```
cd $HOME/Desktop/project_folder node server.js
```

How do I go to a path **AND** execute a command?

Comment: I *think* you can add `$HOME/Desktop/project_folder` to your `NODE_PATH`; then running `node server.js` from *any* directory will work. (Assuming `server.js` doesn't need the directory as its working directory, anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&&`:

`cd $HOME/Desktop/project_folder && node server.js`

You can find more info here: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html